# Pass ArrayList of Intents as extra in adb

Tags: android, android-intent, service, adb

In my code, I have a logic something like this:

```
final ArrayList<Intent> intents = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("extraIntents");
```

I need to send those extraIntents via adb. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `via adb`?

Comment: For example, For testing I start service like this "adb shell am startservice -n SomeClass.class -e city Florida". Just like I am passing "city" as extra, I need to pass another intent as extra.